# matplotlib won't write \approx LaTeX character in legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

For some reason I can't get `matplotlib` to write down the `\approx` LaTeX symbol in a legend.

Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], label='$U_{c} \approx %0.1f$' % 22)
#plt.scatter([0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], label='$U_{c} \simeq %0.1f$' % 22)
#plt.scatter([0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], label='$U_{c} \sim %0.1f$' % 22)
plt.legend(fancybox=True, loc='upper right', scatterpoints=1, fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Notice the first line will not show the `\approx` character or the value after it but both `\simeq` and `\sim` work fine.

I've just opened a [new issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3254) in `matplotlib`'s Github but it occurred to me that I might be doing something wrong so I better ask. If I am, I'll <del>delete</del> close it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a raw string literal: `r'$U_{c} \approx %0.1f$'`.

```
In [8]: plt.scatter([0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], label=r'$U_{c} \approx %0.1f$'%22)
Out[8]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f799249e550>
In [9]: plt.legend(fancybox=True, loc='best')
Out[9]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7f79925e1550>
In [10]: plt.show()
```

[image]

The reason this is happening is as follows:

- Without the `r` infront of the string literal, the string is interpreted by the interpreter as:

  '$U_{c} ' + '\a' + 'pprox 22.0$'
- The `'\a'` is a special escaped character for the ASCII Bell: `BEL`.
- This interpreted string is then passed to the TeX parser.  However, because `'\approx'` got mashed up, the TeX parser doesn't know how to convert your string to proper TeX.

To make sure backslashes (`\`) in the string aren't creating weird escaped characters, add the `r` out front.

Comment: Of course, the `r`. Thanks Bill, that's a great answer.