# Latex on Matplotlib is not being recognised as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, latex

all

I am trying to plot some data on Matplotlib and using Latex on titles. I have done these before and have never encountered this problem. I'm using the following code to plot:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.hist(t_single, bins, rwidth= 0.8, normed= True)
plt.plot(supp, gaussian, 'red')
plt.title(r'Single-selection Estimator ($c_y = $' + str(cy) + ', $c_d = $' + str (cd) + ', $\alpha_0 = $' + str(alpha_0) + ')', fontsize = 16)
plt.legend(['Gaussian', 'Estimator'], loc = 'best', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('t-statistic', fontsize = 14)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)
   2515         try:
-> 2516             result = self._expression.parseString(s)
   2517         except ParseBaseException as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1631                 # catch and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack trace
-> 1632                 raise exc
   1633         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1621         try:
-> 1622             loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
   1623             if parseAll:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1528                 try:
-> 1529                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1530                 except ParseBaseException as pe:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1378                 try:
-> 1379                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1380                 except IndexError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   3716         if self.expr is not None:
-> 3717             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   3718         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1528                 try:
-> 1529                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1530                 except ParseBaseException as pe:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1378                 try:
-> 1379                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1380                 except IndexError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   3394             else:
-> 3395                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
   3396             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1528                 try:
-> 1529                     value = self._parseNoCache(instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1530                 except ParseBaseException as pe:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1382             else:
-> 1383                 loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1384 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   3182         if loc < len(instring):
-> 3183             raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
   3184         elif loc == len(instring):

ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 50), (line:1, col:51)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Google Drive/Mestrado/Tese/Code/Belloni_simulations/sim_plotter.py in <module>()
     59 folder = 'alpha_' + str(alpha_0) + '/'
     60 figname = 'single_vs_double_cy_' + str(cy) + '_cd_' + str(cd) + '_alpha' + str(alpha_0) + '.png'
---> 61 plt.savefig(folder + figname, bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi = 300)
     62 
     63 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    699 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    700     fig = gcf()
--> 701     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    702     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
    703     return res

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in savefig(self, fname, **kwargs)
   1832             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1833 
-> 1834         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   1835 
   1836         if frameon:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2214                     orientation=orientation,
   2215                     dryrun=True,
-> 2216                     **kwargs)
   2217                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2218                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    428             # if toolbar:
    429             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    431         finally:
    432             # if toolbar:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1297 
   1298             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1299                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1300 
   1301             renderer.close_group('figure')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2435             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2436 
-> 2437         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2438 
   2439         renderer.close_group('axes')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in draw(self, renderer)
    713 
    714         with _wrap_text(self) as textobj:
--> 715             bbox, info, descent = textobj._get_layout(renderer)
    716             trans = textobj.get_transform()
    717 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    315                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(clean_line,
    316                                                         self._fontproperties,
--> 317                                                         ismath=ismath)
    318             else:
    319                 w, h, d = 0, 0, 0

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    229         if ismath:
    230             ox, oy, width, height, descent, fonts, used_characters = \
--> 231                 self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
    232             return width, height, descent
    233 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in parse(self, s, dpi, prop)
   3301             self.__class__._parser = Parser()
   3302 
-> 3303         box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)
   3304         font_output.set_canvas_size(box.width, box.height, box.depth)
   3305         result = font_output.get_results(box)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)
   2520                         err.line,
   2521                         " " * (err.column - 1) + "^",
-> 2522                         six.text_type(err)]))
   2523         self._state_stack = None
   2524         self._em_width_cache = {}

ValueError: 
Single-selection Estimator ($c_y = $1, $c_d = $1, $lpha_0 = $0.5)
                                                  ^
Expected end of text (at char 50), (line:1, col:51)
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and, actually, the `\a''' part on`\alpha_0''' is highlighted in a different way, as it were recognising it as another command and not as part of a string that will be interpreted as a Latex command.

Is there a workaround? Latex would make my titles really neat!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib won't write \approx LaTeX character in legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739216/matplotlib-wont-write-approx-latex-character-in-legend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're concatenating strings containing latex in matplotlib it is insufficient to simply put `'r'` at the beginning of the first string, it needs to precede every string being concatenated (those which contain latex commands that is - `'$c_d = $'` for example should not require this). Change

```
plt.title(r'Single-selection Estimator ($c_y = $' + str(cy) + ', $c_d = $' + 
str (cd) + ', $\alpha_0 = $' + str(alpha_0) + ')', fontsize = 16)
```

to

```
plt.title(r'Single-selection Estimator ($c_y = $' + str(cy) + ', $c_d = $' + 
str (cd) + r', $\alpha_0 = $' + str(alpha_0) + ')', fontsize = 16)
```

And the issue should be resolved. This is because only the first string was being interpreted as raw, all subsequent strings that you are concatenated were not being interpreted as raw.

Answer (score 0):

`\a` is an ASCII Bell. You could just use a raw string so that Python doesn't interpret it in this special way:

```
... + r', $\alpha_0 = $' + ...
```